# Regex expression to match even number of double quotation (") not match single one for CSV

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write a regex expression to parse each CSV line. For example, the regex is to match a double quoted string that contains even number of double quotation ("), not single quotation.

For example, the CSV delimiter is tab, \t. I have a line like this:

```
"first column ""end"\tsecond column\t"third \nNewLine\rcolumn\tend"
```

The regex expression will allow me to extract three columns like below:

```
first column ""end
second column
third \nNewLine\rcolumn\tend
```

Please note that there are two double quotes in first column, but it can allow even number of double quotes.

Please note that there are \t within third column, as are \n and \r.

The first and third columns can be quoted if it makes easy to write regex.

Any idea?

Comment: I have tried, but I cannot figure out how to deal with scenario where even number of double quotes within a quoted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about splitting on tabs if and only if an even number of quotes follows?

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subject, 
    @"\t        # Match a tab
    (?=         # if the following regex matches after it:
     (?:        # Match...
      [^""]*""  # Any number of non-quotes, followed by a quote
      [^""]*""  # ditto, to ensure an even number of quotes
     )*         # Repeat as many times as needed
     [^""]*     # Then match any remaining non-quote characters
     $          # until the end of the string.
    )           # End of lookahead assertion", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker How do you achieve your regex level. Could you recommend learning methods and learning materials?

Comment: @Pingpong: I learned most from using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) and its tutorials, and from reading Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions".